# How to print the values after using the push and pop stack

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, dosbox

I have a question about assembly.

```
MOV AX,50
MOV BX,60

PUSH AX
PUSH BX

POP AX
```

The value of AX is 60. My question is how can I print AX. Since all I know is:

```
MOV AH,02
MOV DL,41
INT 21H
```

I am having a difficulty in printing 16-bit registers.

Comment: You will need to convert to text (sequence of ascii digits). Plenty of examples for that.

Comment: You should add that this is an MS-DOS topic. It would be good to add "DOS" as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a duplicate of [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos). I'm sure someone else will close it as such!

Not mentioned in the answer from the link, is that for numbers that stay below 100, so with less than 3 digits, you could use next code:

```
; IN (al=[0,99])
  aam
  add  ax, "00"
  mov  dx, ax
  cmp  dh, "0"
  je   OneDigit
  xchg dl, dh    ; First show the 'tens'
  mov  ah, 02h   ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int  21h
  xchg dl, dh    ; Next show the 'ones'
OneDigit:
  mov  ah, 02h   ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int  21h
```

The `aam` instruction divides AL by 10 and stores the quotient in AH and the remainder in AL.
`add ax, "00"` turns both numbers into characters that you can display on the screen.
The `cmp dh, "0"` `je OneDigit` exists so you don't have to look at an 'ugly' prepended zero for numbers less than 10.

Comment: We have [Displaying Time in Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37129794) for the 2-digit version of the question.  (Although I think that version uses a leading zero for 1-digit numbers.)